# TSQL How to combine subtotals, totals and N-1 subtotal in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of hospital admissions and have to count admissions by ward by Record Type for Adult Ward Types.

The Record type is either 1 or 2, where 1 is a Direct Admission and 2 is a Transfer.

This is an example of the data (Ward and WardType are joined from a lookup table):-

```
IntRefID    RecordType  StartDate   StartTime   Ward    WardType
1205378364  1          25/04/2016   17:30:00    BR WARD    Adult
1205378965  2          26/04/2016   18:00:00    BL WARD      HDU
1205402541  1          21/04/2016   01:15:00    SA UNIT       SA
1205402541  2          26/04/2016   14:36:00    BR WARD    Adult
1205402772  1          21/04/2016   03:11:00    SA UNIT       SA
```

The output I need should look like this -

```
    Ward    RecordType-1    RecordType-2    Total   Transfers from SA
 BR WARD          1            1              2          1
 BL WARD          0            1              1          0
```

When there has been a transfer between wards the IntRefID stays the same.

I'm stuck trying to get totals for 'Transfers from SA'.

The 3rd and 4th rows of the data show an instance where the patient has been admitted to SA Unit then transferred to BR Ward. I need to count this transfer.

There are different types of wards and I only need to count transfers from SA Unit to Adult wards.

I've looked at other posts where you can count the Nth value of a group or in this case N-1, but I can't work out how to combine this with the regular subtotals in one query.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I used a bit of both to come up with a solution that used a temp table to store row numbers partitioned over the IntRefId ordered by start date time. Then did a self join query on IntRefId and [Row Number] = [Row Number]-1

Answer (score 1):

Try below query :-

```
select distinct Ward,
(select count(RecordType) from test5 B where B.Ward=A.Ward AND B.RecordType=1) AS [RecordType-1],
(select count(RecordType) from test5 B where B.Ward=A.Ward AND B.RecordType=2) AS [RecordType-2],
Count(RecordType) over (partition by Ward)  AS Total,
(select count(*) from test5 B where B.Ward=A.Ward AND B.RecordType=A.RecordType AND B.WardType='Adult') AS [Transfers from SA]
from test5 A
```

This query will give you the output like below :-

```
Ward     RecordType-1   RecordType-2    Total   Transfers from SA
BL WARD      0              1             1           0
BR WARD      1              1             2           1
SA UNIT      2              0             2           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select
    Ward,
    SUM(Case recordType when 1 then 1 end) RecordType-1
    SUM(Case recordType when 2 then 1 end) RecordType-2
    COUNT(*) Total,
    case when RecordType = 2 then l.c end [Transfers from SA]
from myTable t
outer apply (
    select
        COUNT(*) c
    from myTable l
    where
        l.RecordType = t.RecordType-1 and 
        Ward = 'SA UNIT' and
        t.startDate+t.StartTime > l.startDate+t.starttime
)l 
where
t.Ward in ('BR WARD','BL WARD')
group by
    t.ward
```